# Query with Mongoose multiple times without nesting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to generate a document with node.js that needs to run multiple unrelated database queries from a mongo database.

Here is my current code:

```
Data.find({}, function(err, results) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  //finished getting data
    res.render('page');
  }
}
```

The problem is if I try to run another query, I seem to have to nest it within the first one so that it waits for the first one to finish before starting, and then I have to put res.render() within the innermost nested query (if I don't, res.render() will be called before the database is finished grabbing data, and it wont be rendered with the page).

What I have to do:

```
Data.find({}, function(err, results) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  //finished getting data

    Data2.find({}, function(err, results2) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      //finished getting data 2
        res.render('page');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am going to have more than 2 queries, so if I keep nesting them it's going to get really messy really fast. Is there a cleaner way to do this, such as a way to make the code wait until all the data is returned and the function is run before continuing with the script?

Comment: What is the use case? Do you want **all** results from both queries or does the data "relate" somehow? There are different answers for both cases. It would also appear that you are actually using [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html), but it would be nice if you confirmed that.

Comment: Yeah I'm using mongoose. The data doesn't relate, I'm trying to create a sitemap, some I'm just generating a list of urls for various sets of data.

Comment: Promises are unnecessary and only make the code more confusing. Just use async.

Answer (score 1):

For mongoose you can probably just do a [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and use [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=example) on the resulting arrays of each query.

As a full demo:

```
var async = require('async'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var d1Schema = new Schema({ "name": String });
var Data1 = mongoose.model("Data1", d1Schema);

var d2Schema = new Schema({ "title": String });
var Data2 = mongoose.model("Data2", d2Schema);

mongoose.set('debug',true);
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

async.series(
  [
    // Clean
    function(callback) {
      async.each([Data1,Data2],function(model,callback) {
        model.remove({},callback)
      },callback);
    },
    // Setup some data
    function(callback) {
      async.each([
        { "name": "Bill", "model": "Data1" },
        { "title": "Something", "model": "Data2" }
      ],function(data,callback) {
        var model = data.model;
        delete data.model;
        mongoose.model(model).create(data,callback);
      },callback);
    },
    // Actual Promise.all demo
    function(callback) {
      Promise.all([
        Data1.find().exec(),
        Data2.find().exec()
      ]).then(function(result) {
        console.log([].concat.apply([],result));
        callback()
      }).catch(callback);
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
)
```

I'm just mixing in [`async`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) there for brevity of example, but the meat of it is in:

```
  Promise.all([
    Data1.find().exec(),
    Data2.find().exec()
  ]).then(function(result) {
    console.log([].concat.apply([],result));
  })
```

Where the `Promise.all()` basically waits for and combines the two results, which would be an "array of arrays" here but the `.concat()` takes care of that. The result will be:

```
[ 
  { _id: 59420fd33d48fa0a490247c8, name: 'Bill', __v: 0 },
  { _id: 59420fd43d48fa0a490247c9, title: 'Something', __v: 0 }
]
```

Showing the objects from each collection, joined together in one array.

You could also use the [`async.concat`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#concat) method as an alternate, but unless you are using the library already then it's probably just best to stick to promises.

Comment: So is promise basically just a javascript function that waits for one or more other functions to finish and then runs a function once they're all done?

Comment: @stackers That is probably best answered by reading the available material. Here's the MDN definition of [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). But more or less your definition is the basic summary. `Promise.all` as also described by the links in the answer specifically awaits **all** Promise objects passed to it to resolve and returns the  combined results within an array. Which we `.concat()` to a single array, as what the answer says. In essence, we combine all "callbacks" into one.